# Eclipse RCP Updating Toolbar and Menu Entries

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am using menu entries and toolbar buttons to link them to actions (AbstractHandler).

For example, I can connect to or disconnect from hardware. If I connect, there are menu and toolbar entries dependent on the connection state. They update after I click in the view or do another action within the view. For UX improvements it would be nice if they update after the action was executed.

Is there a way to update the view programmatically or do I have to implement this differently?

The connect handler is implemented very simple:

```
public class ConnectHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        // Connect to hardware.
        return null;
    }
}
```

The menu and toolbar entries are defined in the `plugin.xml`.

I tried some stuff with the `ICommandService` and `refreshElements`, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Possibly by implements `IElementUpdater` in the handler, but I don't really remember any details.

Comment: Thanks. I recently found out that the menu entries and toolbar items are deactivated/activated with calls of the handlerService: ```originActivation = handlerService.activateHandler(originActivation);``` I would leave it this way but refresh the view after the operations. Is there a way to achieve this?